# how to know the exact data structure in .bin file in matlab

Tags: matlab, fread, bin

I got some data files (.bin) which I do not know what the structure is inside. I try to read it with 'fread' but I need to define the dimensions(number of columns and lines) by myself. Actually I tried but failed to recognize them since the numbers are irregular.Is there anyone who knows how to know the original dimension of these files?

Comment: A .bin file could be anything. What's its origin?

Comment: something about the acceleration. But I don't how if time or az is included.

Comment: Maybe you are reading the data with the wrong byte order? Try playing with the `machineformat` parameter of `fread`. But really, try to find out in what format the file was written originally. Without knowing this, you are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: It's probably hopeless to try to interpret the data inside the file if you don't have a guide of some sort.  You could read 4 bytes and get 4 characters or 1 single-precision floating-point number.  How do you know which one is the correct interpretation ?

Comment: thx. I am gonna ask the person who gave these files. It could be easier.

Comment: A "brute force" method: you could try `numbers = fread(fid, Inf, <datatype>);` Switch through the possible datatypes (see `doc fread` on this) and check which numbers make sense - I'd guess that "single" or "double" are the most promising ones. If there are more than one datatypes included than this is probably hopeless...

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. It's int16 which I got from documents. The data looks much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the syntax:

> `A = fread(fileID)` reads data from a binary file into column vector `A`
>   and positions the file pointer at the end-of-file marker.

where no dimension input is required and then inspect A in MATLAB?

Comment: Actually what I want is only part of the data from .bin file. I need the acceleration of y-coordinate. and I don't get what is the "positions the file pointer at the end-of-file marker." Would you explain it a little bit?

Comment: As I understand it, it's when `fread` has reached the end of the file, i.e. there's nothing left to read. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file.

Comment: still confused. I am green at programming. But I've tried fread(fileID) and outputs a vector. But I don't know which data should I choose. I can't just inspect the whole A in matlab.

Comment: What size is `A`? Try plotting (`plot(A)`)it to see what it looks like, it might give you an idea of what data it is. But really, as Bas has said, you need to have a minimum knowledge of what the file contains.